# how to add gt sign between two crumbs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$('.title').click(function(){
 var cnt = $(this).text();
 var obj = $("<div class='crumb'>" + cnt + "</div>");
 obj.appendTo('#path');
});
```

```css
.crumb{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='path' id='path'>
<div class='crumb'>home</div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>ipsum</div>
```

This works but I need to add `>` sign between two `crumbs`.

i.e. new content should be `home > lorem`

I tried various ways with escaping - `\>`, `&gt;` - without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = $("<div class='crumb'> > " + cnt + "</div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

`var obj = $("<div class='crumb'>" + ">" + cnt + "</div>");`

```js
$('.title').click(function(){
 var cnt = $(this).text();
 var obj = $("<div class='crumb'>" + ">" + cnt + "</div>");
 obj.appendTo('#path');
});
```

```css
.crumb{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='path' id='path'>
<div class='crumb'>home</div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
$('.title').click(function(){
 var cnt = $(this).text();
 var html = "<div class='crumb'>" + ">" + cnt + "</div>";
  $('#path').append(html);
  var crumbs =  $('#path').find('.crumb');
  
  var crumbHas = 0;
  html = '';
  $.each(crumbs, function(index, element){
    var cnt1 = $(this).text();
     if(crumbHas != 1){
         html += "<div class='crumb'>"+ cnt1 + "</div>";
     }
      if(cnt1.indexOf(cnt) > -1){
      crumbHas = 1;
     }
  })
 $('#path').empty();
  $('#path').append(html);
});
```

```css
.crumb{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='path' id='path'>
<div class='crumb'>home</div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>text</div>


<div id="test">
</div>
</div>
```